# Can't print the top part of a circle

Tags: prusa-i3, print-failure

I'm trying to print the painter's tripod from [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=36uU1Z7OiJg):

[image]

I can't get it to finish the print. It always fails towards the top when it's closing the circles. I've tried brims and even glue for adhesion, and different settings for inlays, perimeters, etc... my bed levelling is correct and my first layer is perfect. The prints come out beautiful, but they always fail there. I have a theory but since I don't have a camera set up I can't confirm, but I feel like the nozzle gets stuck against the previous layer, as if when it's coming from the other side of the "bridge" completing the upper layers of the circle, it get's to the other side of the gap and it finds that the filament has hardened just a bit higher than when it's going to print, and therefore knocks the piece to the side (despite using glue!!), and from that point on, obviously, total mess and I have to cancel. Just a theory though. Any ideas of what else could this be or what to do about it?

Printer is a Prusa i3 Mark3S

Comment: did you try **support** structure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to print an unsupported edge up there - the top edge has nothing to rest on and thus sags down. As a result, the print failed.

To remedy this, activate printing with support. With a support angle of 80° or tree support, you could minimize the needed material.

Comment: This answer could be a lot more useful/helpful suggesting how to configure support for this model. It's likely to be a huge waste of material and hard to remove without tuning. I suspect "tree" support might do well. But classic support set for just sharp overhangs may work well too.

Comment: Hi Trish, I thought about that but i've printed circles before (not as big and not in a slanted plane, however) and I worked always fine. I always understood that the printer would be able to do the "angle" of the circle without the support, as opposed to a hanging 90deg corner. I'll give it a try anyway. Thanks

Comment: Added supports and printed like a charm. Thank you!